Custom YUM groups that span repos?
Having a hard time finding what I would have assumed would be basic functionality.
Basically I want to have a group defined as 'mygroup' that includes packages from both BaseOS and AppStream in RHEL9.
I've tried creating a single comps file that includes the group information and creating each repo with that comps file, but this usually results in yum (anaconda kickstart) complaining No match for group package: foo for a subset of the packages in the group.
For example the layout

BaseOS/foo.rpm
AppStream/bar.rpm
AppStream/baz.rpm

And the comps file:
  <group>
    <id>mygroup</id>
    <packagelist>
      <packagereq type="mandatory">foo</packagereq>
      <packagereq type="mandatory">bar</packagereq>
      <packagereq type="mandatory">baz</packagereq>
    </packagelist>
  </group>
</comps>

Creating the repos:
createrepo -g comps.xml AppStream/
createrepo -g comps.xml BaseOS/

And my kickstart:
%packages
@mygroup

Usually results in some of the packages not being found, the installation continuing anyway (despite being marked mandatory), and simply not installing them.
Is there a secret to getting a yum group to span across repos? Or is a group a subset of what makes a repo a 'repo'?

What do you need to pull in from BaseOS that isn't already  Required as dependencies of what you want in AppStream?

@JohnMahowald I'm trying to support an application that isn't installed from RPM that has particular dependencies from both repos. I also have separate repos for things like NVIDIA and EPEL rpms I'm hoping any answer can be extended to support.
